Is power of a test lower bounded by the significance level?
Here's an example that makes me ask this question. Let the significance level be $\alpha$.
Suppose we have a normal distribution with a known standard deviation $\sigma = 1$.
$H_0$: The mean of the distribution is 0.
$H_1$: The mean of the distribution is something else.
I get a sample x from the distribution.
The power of this test is the chance of rejecting the null hypothesis when $H_1$ is true. Let us call the something else mean $\mu_1$. In that case, the power is defined in terms of the c.d.f of the standard normal distribution $\phi$:
$$1-\beta = 1 - (\phi(z_{\alpha/2} - \mu_1) - \phi(z_{-\alpha/2} - \mu_1))$$
By moving $\mu_1$ away from 0, we trade some of the tail area on side with the inside area on the other. So, the minimum achieved from above is $\alpha$, when $\mu_1 = 0$.
My question is, does this work for other examples as well?
Another case:
Suppose we have a distribution with an unknown shape. Let the significance level be 5%.
$H_0$: The distribution is standard normal.
$H_1$: The distribution is 1-sub-gaussian with zero mean.
Now, suppose I get a sample $x=2$. By definition, we have to reject the null hypothesis. But, $H_1$ seems even less likely.
Here, the power of the test being lower bounded by $\alpha$ doesn't hold. But, I feel that the test itself ends up being ill-defined in crafting a situation like that. Maybe it is like finding something wrong with a proof that concludes $1=2$.
Are there other (better?) examples where power is not lower bounded by the significance level?
Similar question here: Can type 1 error give lower bound on power of test, if null-hypothesis is false
I feel I have dived deeper, so I'm posting this here.

If you feel your question is not covered by the indicated duplicate please edit (including the title) to focus directly on the specific difference in your question

Plenty of tests in common use are biased against some alternatives of interest. This is quite common with tests that have broad/omnibus alternatives.


Are there other (better?) examples where power is not lower bounded by the significance level?

If we consider the most powerful test, then the power is always above or equal to the significance level. See the question Proof of the statement "the best test is unbiased" which is about the statement whether the power is above the significance level for the optimal likelihood ratio test.
One can always make silly tests with very low power. Examples where the power is below the significance occur when the model is wrong or when the test is not working correctly.
An example of a silly test: we test whether a coin is fair for heads and tails and flip it $250$ times and reject the hypothesis when the number of heads is $125$. That gives a test with a $5\%$ significance level, but the power to reject the test, when the true heads:tails odds are not 1:1 and will be lower than that $5\%$.
Other less extreme cases might occur when some model has been wrong, and the rejection criterium happens more likely given the null hypothesis (which should equal the significance level) than some alternative hypothesis.
To look for examples you can search for ROC curves getting below the diagonal. One such example is: ROC curve crossing the diagonal
